# Append method not updating a list with loop indices

Tags: python, list, for-loop, append

Here is the code:

```
#part of the initial list

T_sdlist = [221.97198, 219.32863, 215.86764, 187.47008, 460.75941, 314.24377, 241.74913, 300.0, 300.0, 232.70892, 232.33307, 453.53369, 495.62097, 666.0764, 300.0, 567.77315, 704.02937, 596.72463, 463.69465, 520.46281, 300.0, 593.98425]
badvalues = []

for j in range(len(T_sdlist)):
  if T_sdlist[j] == 300.00:
    print(j)
    badvalues.append(j)

print(badvalues)
for k in badvalues:
  T_sdlist.pop(k)

print(T_sdlist)
print(len(T_sdlist))
```

I am trying to get rid of values equaling 300 in the list `T_sdlist`, and I also want to record the index of these values, which is why I append the list `badvalues` with the loop index j. But when I print `badvalues` it returns an empty list. To figure out the problem, I also printed the j value after every iteration, but it returns nothing. But when I use `badvalues` for updating `T_sdlist`, that works.
How come the list `badvalues` exist and yet prints as an empty list?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. What are the contents of `T_sdlist`?

Comment: I print `badvalues` and it gives indeed every bad value index. So I don't know where the problem is. On the other hand `T_sdlist.pop(k)` is wrong.  If you pop once then all indeces of your lists are not the same anymore and you will start poping random items. + you may even go out of range.

Comment: For some reason I'm only getting [] when printing `badvalues`. @Skapis9999

Comment: @TroyBean do what Unmitigated suggested. What's your initial list?

Comment: I added a part of the initial list in the question, I'm working with data so the full original list is a bit too long. @Skapis9999

Comment: `badvalues = [7, 8, 14, 20]`  for me. WIth your code.

Comment: Yeah it's really weird. Anyways Grisha's code works, so I'll just stick with that. Thanks for the help @Skapis9999

Answer (score 1):

```
badvalues = [ix for ix, val in enumerate(T_sdlist) if val == 300.0]
T_sdlist = [x for x in T_sdlist if x != 300.0]
```

Comment: `T_sdlist = [x in T_sdlist if x != 300.0]` returns `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` to me

Comment: Sorry, was my bad, now I update the code

Comment: Not it works fine.